# Calculate percentage

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi this code gives me employee salaries and manager salaries.

```
SELECT E.EMP_FNAME AS MANAGER, E.EMP_SALARY, D.DEPT_NO, A.EMP_FNAME AS EMPLOYEE, A.EMP_SALARY
 FROM EMPLOYEE E, EMPLOYEE A, DEPARTMENT D
 WHERE E.EMP_NIN = A.EMP_MANAGER
 AND A.EMP_MANAGER = D.EMP_MANAGER;
```

![alt text][1]

How can i only show the employees that have a salary within 10% of their manager salary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to allow for employees earning more than their managers (you know it would happen, in a different, better world) just include this in the WHERE clause:

```
AND  A.SALARY BETWEEN (E.SALARY * 0.9) and (E.SALARY * 1.1)
```

**edit**

This uses simple mathematics.   0.9 = 90% and 1.1 = 110%; this line restricts the resultset to EMPLOYEE records where the SALARY is with +/- 10% of their manager's SALARY.  If you are certain that employees can never earn more than their manager then you need a simpler greater than test...

```
AND  A.SALARY >= (E.SALARY * 0.9)
```

Comment: employees shall not earn more than managers according to my homework

Comment: what are the values 0.9 and 1.1

Comment: @apc HEY do you know how to write a procedure/function to show that an amployee pay may not exceed their managers?

Comment: @DAVID - sounds like a fresh question to me